# c# wpf interface instance creation

Tags: wpf

How can i create an instance of an interface in c# wpf and the major issue is that its been declared in static class named **"GLOBAL";**

Interface name is **"IcuttingMac"**

```
 public static class Global  {

public static DataTable ProgramNamesTable = null;
//public const string BuildNo = "Build No. 1.0.0 dt. 2014/06/11";
//public const string CopyRight = "(c) Proteck Machinery Pvt. Ltd.,\nChennai, INDIA";


 public static Cutting_Machine.CutMACStatus cutmacstatus;


 public static ICuttingmac Icutmacobj;
// public static ICuttingMac Icuttingobj = new ICuttingMac();

 ////UNCOMMENT THIS for PROTECH PLC
 public const string DATAPATH = "\\Hard Disk\\cmp";
```

this s the interface created in another file pls help me fix;

this is throwing an exception that new instance to be created;

```
public interface ICuttingmac : IDisposable {

      #region Settings
      CMModel cmmodel { get; set; }
      ProgStartup progstartup { get; set; }
      float Homeposition { get; set; }
      float Stackposition { get; set; }
      float Rearlimit { get; set; }
      float Frontlimit { get; set; }
      float FrontlimitwFC { get; set; }
      int PositionMUL { get; set; }
      int PositionDIV { get; set; }
      float Slowjogspeed { get; set; }
      float Fastjogspeed { get; set; }
      float Inchingdist { get; set; }
      short Maxcutsperknife { get; set; }
      float Homespeed { get; set; }
      float HomeAccl { get; set; }
      ushort Knifespeed { get; set; }
      ushort Knifechangespeed { get; set; }
      ushort Kniferapidspeed { get; set; }
      ushort Knifeslowspeed { get; set; }
      ushort KnifeDECspeed1 { get; set; }
      ushort KnifeDECspeed2 { get; set; }
      ushort Kniferamp { get; set; }
      ushort Clampmult { get; set; }
      ushort ClampDiv { get; set; }
      ushort ActKnifeAO { get; }
      ushort ActClmpAO { get; }

      void Setknifespeed(int ix, ushort speed);
      //void LoadCmsettings() { }
      //void SaveCmsettings() { }
      ushort Getknifespeed(int ix);
      #endregion
```

Comment: You cannot create an instance of an interface. You'll need to create an instance of a class which implements that interface.

Comment: that is a static class la how can i create an instance

Comment: Not the class which declared it, but the one which [implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) it. See the answer below and read it carefully.

Comment: Dude first go through the interface and class link which i given below. once you have a basic understanding about interface and class then you will get the answer to your question by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First you need this

- An interface is like an abstract base class. Any class or struct that
  implements the interface must implement all its members.
- An interface can't be instantiated directly. Its members are
  implemented by any class or struct that implements the interface.
- Interfaces can contain events, indexers, methods, and properties.
  Interfaces contain no implementation of methods.
- A class or struct can implement multiple interfaces. A class can
  inherit a base class and also implement one or more interfaces.

[Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

[class (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx)